# Web Service(asmx) ERROR - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a problem with the Web Service (asmx) while I'm trying to send/receive large requests/responses... I'm keep getting error "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive"

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://test.smth.cin:443/ws/1.0") as HttpWebRequest;
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
request.ClientCertificates.Add(Cert);
request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", @"https://test.smth.cin:443/ws/1.0" + p_SOAPAction);
request.Timeout = 2200000;
StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(),System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
requestWriter.Write(str_SOAP);
requestWriter.Flush();
requestWriter.Close(); 



   HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    Stream responsedata = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader responsereader = new StreamReader(responsedata);

    WS_Response ws_r = new WS_Response();
    XmlDocument WS_XML_Response = new XmlDocument();

    byte[] encodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str_SOAP);

    // Put the byte array into a stream and rewind it to the beginning
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encodedString);
    ms.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;
    WS_XML_Response.Load(ms);
```

I also set `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="200000" executionTimeout="360000" />` in webconfig and I'm still getting an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: I checked with fiddler and I always get "504 Gateway Timeout"...

Answer (score 0):

Please change u r maxRequestLenght=Int32.MaxValue();

which will be somewhere
=2,147,481,263

Answer (score 0):

When I've seen this error in the past, it's been a problem where the response XML is not valid and the connection is closed due to an exception that occurs during the processing of the invalid XML. I would try to save off the raw XML request data and then validate that XML data against the schema for your web service. You'll might find that there's something invalid in the response XML that's causing the connection to be forcibly closed.

Comment: I checked and XML response is valid. I think it's something wrong on server where web service is hosted. I checked with others who use this web service and they have the same problem...